# Can a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ have uncountably many cluster points?

Tags: real-analysis

Can a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ have uncountably many cluster points? I was curious about this after reading this: [Example of a sequence with countable many cluster points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191358/example-of-a-sequence-with-countable-many-cluster-points).

In that post, there is given a sequence with countably infinite cluster points. Hence I was curious about the uncountable case, if it is even possible.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\sigma=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be any enumeration of $\Bbb Q$, the set of rational numbers; this is possible, since $\Bbb Q$ is countable. Then it’s a nice exercise to prove that every real number is a cluster point of $\sigma$.

Comment: Of course the last part depends on your definition of a real number!

Comment: @Cameron: How so?

Comment: Well I mean to say that some would say that's true by definition, so it's vacuously true. Not that it has to be checked. It was clumsy wording on my part.

Comment: @Cameron: Even if you define the reals as equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences of rationals, you still have to show that any fixed enumeration of $\Bbb Q$ has a *subsequence* converging to each given real.

Comment: Oh I see your point. Yeah I guess it's not quite trivial but there isn't too much work to do. Just a few lines of reasoning.