# Can a countable nowhere dense set have uncountably many accumulation points?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have a set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ that is countable and nowhere dense. Is it possible that this set has uncountably many accumulation points?

I think the answer is no. I have tried to somehow map the accumulation points to $S$ in such a way that I would only map countably many accumulation points to any point in $S$ but I did not succeed in this.

My question is related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1637057/can-a-sequence-in-mathbbr-have-uncountably-many-cluster-points). That question drops the assumption of being nowhere dense, after which the answer is **yes**. However, the example (rationals) are far from being nowhere dense, making me think that the answer to my question is no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can. Call $C$ Cantor's set, which is closed, uncountable and with empty interior. $\Bbb Q\cap C$ is dense in $C$, because it contains all the points of $C$ that have finite ternary expansion. Therefore, $\Bbb Q\cap C$ is an example of what you've asked.

More generally, $\Bbb R$ is a separable metric space, therefore *all* its subsets have a countable dense subset (i.e. for all $X\subseteq \Bbb R$ there is some countable $S\subseteq X$ such that $\overline S\supseteq X$). Any such subset $S$ coming from a closed uncountable subset $X$ with empty interior will do.

Comment: I see. And if I use a fat Cantor's set, then I get that the set of accumulation points is not only uncountable but also can have positive measure!

Comment: Even more extreme, given any perfect nowhere dense set (which could have positive measure), there exists an **isolated set** whose set of accumulation points is equal to that perfect nowhere dense set. This can be accomplished by letting the isolated set be the collection of midpoints of the (bounded) open complementary intervals of the perfect set (or more generally, for each of the complementary intervals choose a finite set of points anywhere within that interval).

Comment: @user2316602: Keep in mind that some Cantor sets, even those with positive measure, contain no rational numbers. But Saucy O'Path's additional observation about separability takes care of things.